# gethostbyname problem

Tags: c, unix, networking, sockets, gethostbyname

I wish to use "gethostbyname" in my Suse m/c but it is not returning any structure.

but on the other systems it is working fine what could be the issue with my m/c ??

Comment: Any code would be helpful, some debugging  stuff (gdb), or simple print statements would help a lot this community to solve your problem.

Comment: did you check every returned value and so?

Comment: What is the value of `h_errno` after the call? What does `getent <hostname>` give on shell command line?

Comment: stupid question - what does 'm/c' mean?

Comment: @mouviciel: you mean getent ahosts <hostname>

Comment: Or actually getent hosts, not ahosts, since he's asking about the obsolete gethostbyname.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the new way of doing it is using [getaddrinfo](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)  see [beej guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfo)

Answer (score 0):

To gethostbyname to work an entry in /etc/hosts to be made ... :)
I was missing that thanks for answers.

Comment: Needing an entry in your hosts file means your DNS server isn't working right. Are you sure that's not the real source of the problem?

Comment: That is the source of problem I passing hostname but there was no entry in /etc/hosts so it was not able to resolve the IP .

Answer (score 0):

If “ping somehost” on the command line works for you, gethostbyname should work, too, when used correctly. Read manpage resolv.conf(5) for details on how to configure name resolution.

If you get ping working but your code still fails, please post an example.